# Error on deploy at google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Help me. I'm bad at English. I'll simply explain my problem. I want to deploy my webpage at google app engine but i don't know what's wrong my computer. I'm happy to see your answer to my question....Thanks you

2014-07-14 13:21:14 Running command: "['C:\Python27\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=*****@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\Users\*****']"

01:21 PM Application: rugged-destiny-633; version: 1

01:21 PM Host: appengine.google.com

01:21 PM 
Starting update of app: rugged-destiny-633, version: 1

01:21 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for *****@gmail.com: 01:21 PM Scanning files on local disk.

Could not guess mimetype for css/bootstrap-theme.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.

Could not guess mimetype for css/bootstrap.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.

Could not guess mimetype for css/bootstrap.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.

Could not guess mimetype for css/bootstrap-theme.css.map.  Using application/octet-stream.
01:21 PM Cloning 21 static files.

01:21 PM Cloning 15 application files.

01:21 PM Uploading 11 files and blobs.

2014-07-14 13:21:39,691 ERROR appcfg.py:2488 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2329, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2467, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1402, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1361, in SendBatch
    payload,

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)**

01:21 PM Rolling back the update.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in 
    run_file(**file**, globals())

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5220, in 
    main(sys.argv)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5211, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2886, in Run
    self.action(self)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4890, in **call**
    return method()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3682, in Update

```
self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3735, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3618, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2329, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2467, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1402, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1361, in SendBatch
    payload,

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

2014-07-14 13:21:41 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.

=============================

My app.yaml file is following.

application: rugged-destiny-633
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /

script: semodol3.html

- url: /css

  static_dir: css
- url: /img

  static_dir: img
- url: /js
  static_dir: js

Comment: Please format your question to make it more appealing

Comment: Oh... i dont know how format my question ;;;

Comment: can you teach me? how can i format...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks ! I'm first day in stackoverflow ...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess, but you may want to check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150956/google-app-engine-launcher-throws-ascii-codec-error-when-deploying-image-file) if this is your problem (not very experienced with google app engine). I also don't have enough rep to just comment this, but oh well...